# How can I load package.json into a variable in Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I want to get the version attribute from my code into a variable in my playbook.
I have the following tasks in my playbook:

```
- name: get version from package
  shell: cat "/path/to/package.json"
  register: package_json

- set_fact: package="{{ package_json.stdout | from_json }}"

- debug: msg="{{ package.version }}"
```

That results in the error:

```
fatal: [x.x.x.x] => One or more undefined variables: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'version'
```

However, if I change the debug statement to the following:

```
- debug: msg="{{ package }}
```

Then I see the following on the console:

```
ok: [x.x.x.x] => {
    "msg": "{u'name': u'my_project', u'version': u'2.0.4-build.723.6907', ...
```

How can I access this attribute since `{{ package.version }}` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `package` itself is a dictionary.

So can you please try:

```
{{ package.value.version }}
```